# repmgr - recover from failed primary?

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

Hi all using repmgr to test some failover logic

Unsure what command is needed to recover from this situation:

```
repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf cluster show
 ID | Name | Role    | Status               | Upstream | Location | Priority | Timeline | Connection string                                                        
----+------+---------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | rep3 | primary | * running            |          | default  | 100      | 1        | xxx
 2  | 2    | standby | ! running as primary |          | default  | 100      | 2        | xxx
```

Series of events:

- Primary alive
- Standby alive
- Primary shutdown
- Standby promoted to primary
- Primary started

We probably want to change the role of the old primary to become a standby now?

Comment: Somewhat similar to: https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/repmgr/issues/535